# Return List<Object[]> with spring JPA BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring JPA framework. I have a requirement where the query is dynamically generated with 'n' number of columns and multiple where conditions. I was able to generate dynamic sql. Now i want to execute this query and tried the foll.

```
List<Object[]> reportResults1 = namedJdbcTemplate.query(selectSql.toString(), new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Object[].class));
```

I get this errror:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [[Ljava.lang.Object;]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Ljava.lang.Object;.<init>()
```

I have worked this with hibenrate and it does work fine. This is sample code in hibernate.

```
query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
List<Object[]> reportResults = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
```

What am i missing with spring JPA. How do i get it work with BeanPropertyRowMapper and return list of object[]? any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not JPA nor Hibernate problem. Check the documentation for [BeanPropertyRowMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html).

> Column values are mapped based on matching the column name as obtained from result set meta-data to public setters for the corresponding properties. The names are matched either directly or by transforming a name separating the parts with underscores to the same name using "camel" case.

What happens is about that mapper tries to create `new Object[?]`. The question mark stands for missing dimension. That will not work. Even if it did `Object[n]` does not have setters/getters for the fields you will get.

Perhaps you could use `RowMapper` of your own. You could declare class like (just as an example, not tested, might need adjusting):

```
public class ObjectArrayMapper implements RowMapper<Object[]> {
    @Override
    public Object[] mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        var columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        var array = new Object[columnCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            array[i] = rs.getObject(i);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

and call:

```
List<Object[]> reportResults1 = 
    namedJdbcTemplate.query(selectSql.toString(),
        new ObjectArrayMapper());
```

Comment: thank you for replying back. Do you know what other ways i can do to get it work?

Comment: @JNPW check update